# Send message to multiple email addresses per subscriber

Tags: mailchimp

I want to add more than 1 email address to a single MailChimp subscriber. I want to do this because I am running a program with various contacts, and need to make sure each contact is kept up to date.

My current workaround is to make new entries for each individual contact. This means that any time an event's address, time, or location is changed, it must be manually updated for every contact.

[A support ticket from 2014](https://formidableforms.com/help-desk/add-multiple-emails-in-form-to-mailchimp-list/) stated that the feature wasn't currently available in MailChimp. I'm hoping there may be a workaround or alternative service I can use.

**How can I add multiple emails for a single subscriber in MailChimp?**

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you'd like to add multiple email addresses to one subscriber. I was able to verify that each subscriber is only able to have one email address attached.

An alternative would be to create a custom field for an "Alternative email address", but this would only enable you to segment and you would not be able to send to those alternate addresses so i'm not sure if that would work for you.